# SSD works but can't install OS

Tags: boot, ssd, operating-systems

For the past 6 years I had 3 SSDs, at some point they started acting up, Windows doesn't start, `chkdsk /f /r /b` prints some problem and I can't fix them. I can use them to save files but neither Windows nor Ubuntu can be installed anymore.

Windows gives an error after some hours, Ubuntu stays in the same step forever. I plug them in another PC, slow format them, run chkdsk, no errors or warnings, but when I try to install any OS... same error.

What causes an SSD to work just fine for storage, but can't boot up an OS?
Is there some magic tool I just couldn't find that will fix this?

Also, am I just unlucky or maybe some low-quality hardware is causing this? Motherbord, power supply, SATA cable... All the SSDs are Samsung ssd 860 evo.

Edit:
Good news! Running Seagate Seatools "Fix All (Long)" I could again install Windows on it. It's says the SSD's life is at 79%...
Still no idea what caused it but I'll follow the tips in the comments about installing everything (and the TEMP path variable) on another drive. Maybe this new one will last longer

Comment: Have you updated their firmware? Anything interesting in SMART/diagnostics?

Comment: @gronostaj as soon as I buy a new one and install Windows I will tell you... :|

Comment: Low quality SSDs can do this.  Good / high quality SSDs should not.  Make sure you are installing correctly (GPT, UEFI, Secure Boot

Comment: @John, I don't regard Samsung as low quality.  That is what I am using.  Mine is lasting, but I am taking precautions.

Comment: Good Samsung SSDs will last a long time. I think they are good drives and that is what I use.

Comment: Changing SATA cable/socket is always worth doing - frankly, they're a horrible design & don't respond well to any sideways pressure on the sockets. Make sure there is no stress at all anywhere, especially when closing up the case.

Comment: Three in a row makes me wonder about the host system or environment. I've used Samsung drives too and they're just fine, haven't seen the issues you have.

Comment: Despite the downvotes to my answer, I still maintain that,  that the portions of your SSD required for the OS are damaged.   This is borne out by the number of failures you have had and are confirmed by chkdsk.  While the app or OS can not dictate where the data is written by the firmware, the firmware is not writing data randomly, all over the drive.  I recommend that if you are replacing it, try and move away parts of the storage away to another drive. In particular often written ones such as temp or download